# Prolog Remove element from list

Tags: list, prolog

I have the following fact to remove all occurences of a element in a list. Although the output is correct, the element is just replaced for a blank space

```
remover( _, [], []).
remover( R, [R|T], [T2]) :- remover( R, T, T2).
remover( R, [H|T], [H|T2]) :- H \= R, remover( R, T, T2).
```

When I call remover the output is :

```
remover(3,[1,2,3,4,3],Res)
Res = [1, 2, [4, []]]
```

I also have the following fact to remove only the first occurence but the output is the same from above

```
remover_primeira( _, [], []).
remover_primeira( R, [R|T], [T2]) :-remover_primeira( R, T, T2),!.
remover_primeira( R, [H|T], [H|T2]) :- H \= R, remover_primeira( R, T, T2).
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should not wrap `T2` in a singleton list in the second clause, it should be:

```
remover( _, [], []).
remover( R, [R|T], T2) :- remover( R, T, T2).
remover( R, [H|T], [H|T2]) :- H \= R, remover( R, T, T2).
```

In case you only need to remove the *first* occurrence, then you should not recurse from the moment you found that element:

```
remover( _, [], []).
remover( R, [R|T], T).
remover( R, [H|T], [H|T2]) :- H \= R, remover( R, T, T2).
```

Comment: What about the remove only the first occurrence? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @FábioPires: then you should not recurse given you fond the element.

Comment: thank you so much. I am finding recursion in Prolog hard to understand

Answer (score 2):

The solution by @WillemVanOnsem, derived from the OP code, uses *term unification* when comparing the element to be removed with the elements of the list (an alternative would be to use *term equality*). The solution works for ground terms. But can result in unexpected results when the terms are not ground. For example:

```
| ?- remover(a(_), [a(1), b(2), a(3), b(4)], List).

List = [b(2),a(3),b(4)] ? ;
no
```

Consider the following alternative definition of the `remover/3` predicate:

```
remover(_, [], []).
remover(R, [H|T], T2) :- \+ H \= R, remover(R, T, T2).
remover(R, [H|T], [H|T2]) :- H \= R, remover(R, T, T2).
```

With this solution, the query above gives:

```
| ?- remover(a(_), [a(1), b(2), a(3), b(4)], List).         

List = [b(2),b(4)] ? ;
no
```

Be sure to have a clear understanding of the semantics you want for the predicate.

Answer (score 0):

You can also solve it like this:

```
del(E1,[E1|T1],L2) :- T1 == L2, !. %base case
del(E1,[H1|T1],[H2|T2]) :- H1 == H2, del(E1,T1,T2). %general case
```

I'm not sure if there's an optimization to be done, because I did it in a couple of minutes, but it works quite nicely.